# phonegap application on blackberry OS 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I deployed my phonegap application on android and it worked just fine, also when i deployed it on Blackberry bold 9900 emulator there also it worked fine but as soon as i deployed it on blackberry curve 8520, the application failed entirely.

I read somewhere that BB OS 5 does not support Ajax call but couldn't figure out a way to stop the ajax calling on an OS 5 device.

Comment: You can detect the userAgent and maybe there is something useful in there that can allow you determine what kind of BB you have.

Comment: i checked and found out that Blackberry OS 5 does not suppport ajax calls and also it dsnt have HTML5 support.

Comment: So you can either stop supporting BB OS 5 or put a different code for BB OS 5.

Comment: yepp.. thats what i was thinking of..